# is there a way to limit the schema size in PostgreSQL-14?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I wanted to create a schema that should not exceed 20 GB of data. I am using PostgreSQL-14 version.

please advice me

Thank you.

Comment: No, not possible. However, you could run a cronjob that checks the size and does something when a threshold has been reached.

Comment: @Vérace I have never done anything with that extension, didn't know that it existed. Heikki Linnakangas is someone who really knows PostgreSQL, that is something to consider. But it's a long list of caveats and there haven't been any updates the last 5 years.

Comment: @Vérace Why so negative? It's the beauty of a project like PostgreSQL, only functionality that is really wanted by the majority will be worked on. And when you needs something special, you can always build it yourself or fund it. Something like temporal tables can be done in a slowly changing dimension, works really well in PostgreSQL using the tstzrange-data type. Just the syntax is slightly easier to work with, but when you use pipelines for your database maintenance that hardly makes any difference.

Comment: You could mount a 20GB partition on your file system and set up a [tablespace](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createtablespace.html) there. Problem is that the parameter `default_tablespace` can be altered on cluster, database, role, session or transaction level, not a specific schema/namespace. If your goal was to limit a specific user's schema space, you could effectively do it that way, changing their default tablespace. If by *schema* you don't mean one specific *namespace* in a db but the entire structure on the db, then you can set that tablespace default for the entire db.

Comment: @FrankHeikens - I'm certainly not negative wrt PostgreSQL, quite the opposite. For example, its extension framework is beyond compare (Timescaledb, Citus... list goes on and on) even by the big boys. Its more disappointment than negativity - and the fact that people (and big hitters at that) have put **a lot** of work into all the features I mentioned and I think that it's a pity that PostgreSQL doesn't have them whereas others do. Your comment about ranges is well taken. Don't understand "but when you use pipelines for your database maintenance that hardly makes any difference."?

Comment: @Vérace When using scripts to generate your DDL, these scripts can automatically add the SCD functionality in your DDL. When that is done, the simplicity is comparable with temporal tables in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/external-extensions.html) written by [Heikki Linnakangas](https://github.com/hlinnaka/pg_quota).

On his [profile](https://www.postgresql.org/community/contributors/) on the PostgreSQL site, he's listed as in the "Major Contributors" section:

> 2 phase commit support, reworked FSM and VM, replication/transactions,
> indexing and much more

He's now heading up the [Neon Serverless PostgreSQL] project (https://neon.tech/), a (fascinating) derviative of PostgreSQL - it's fair to say that he knows a thing or two about PostgreSQL!

### Caveats: (from the GitHub page)

Limitations

- Quotas are counted against the direct owner of each relation. You cannot have quotas on groups, for example.
- The owner of each relation is determined by the effects of committed transactions only. Uncommitted transactions are not taken into account. For example, if you change the owner of a table with ALTER TABLE, the table is counted towards the old owner's quota until the transaction commits. Likewise, if you create a table and load it with data in the same transaction, it is not counted towards the user's quota until the transaction commits.
- Tracking disk usage is implemented by periodically scanning through the data directory. That can be slow, if you have a lot of tables or partitions. It also means that there is a significant delay before changes to disk usage is reflected in the quota status.
- Quotas are only checked at the beginning of INSERT and COPY statements. As long as the user has not exceeded the quota at the beginning of the statement, the INSERT or COPY is allowed to go through, even if it causes the quota to be exceeded.
- **As a consequence of the above limitation , quotas are rather "soft". It's not hard to exceed them if you try.**

That's a **lot** of caveats! So, you wouldn't want to implement this extension in a potentially hostile environment.

I've always thought that this is an area where PostgreSQL **really** falls down with respect to other RDBMS's.